# Matrix calculations in Python when last row depends on the value of previous row

Tags: numpy, matrix

I am initializing 2 matrices as :

```
import numpy as np   

mtx1 = np.zeros(shape=(5,10)) #this will be the resulting matrix 
mtx2 = np.random.randn(5,10)  #random number matrix

mtx1[0] = mtx2[0]             #first row is equal to random number matrix first row
```

Now what i am trying to complete **mtx1** as the previous **mtx1** row + the equivalent row of **mtx2** so the result would be the equivalent of doing :

```
mtx1[1] = mtx1[0] +  mtx2[1]
mtx1[2] = mtx1[1] +  mtx2[2]
mtx1[3] = mtx1[2] +  mtx2[3]
mtx1[4] = mtx1[3] +  mtx2[4]
mtx1[5] = mtx1[4] +  mtx2[5]
...
mtx1[10] = mtx1[9] +  mtx2[10]
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing it if i am working with large matrices ?

Comment: are you aware of `np.cumsum`? Btw. If you want 10 rows it's `shape=(10, 5)` not the other way round. And the last row is no `9`, not `10`. Just saying.

Comment: This was a poor example choice from my part, what i wanted to understand is when you have a situation in a matrix when the last row is dependable from the value of the previous row what is the best practice. I oversimplified using a sum example. but generically i would like an answer for any type of function like :       
    row(n) = f(row(n-1))

Comment: For an arbitrary function I'm not sure you can avoid the loop. In that case if you need the speed Cython may be worth a look. If it happens to be a two argument `ufunc`, then it will probably have an `accumulate` method. For example `np.cumsum` is more or less a shorthand for `np.add.accumulate`.

Comment: @RiskTech I'll update my answer but the fastest way would like be to use `np.roll` or `pd.DataFrame.shift`. This works if you want to apply some arbitrary function but is only really efficient if you only care about the i-1 row(or j-1 column)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments by Paul Panzer, if you want to get a cumulative sum you just use `.cumsum(axis=0)`, in this case, this would look as follows:

```
#create matrix (note correction to 10 rows, 5 columns)
mtx2 = np.random.randn(10,5)

#take the cumulative sum
mtx1 = mtx2.cumsum(axis=0)
```

The output is here:

```
#check that the output matrix is the same size
In [17]: mtx1.shape
Out[17]: (5, 10)

#show that the first row in input is same as in output
In [24]: (mtx1[0,:] == mtx2[0,:]).all()
Out[24]: True
```

### Update (12/30/2017):

To do an quick operation between two matrices in which we care about the ith and the (i-1)th row, you can use the [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) function which shifts all rows(columns) by an arbitrary amount. For example, suppose you wish to add the (i-1)th row (or some functional output thereof) to row i, then we simply do

```
#initiate a simple 10 by 5 matrix of random integers between 0 and 10
mtx2 = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,5))

#add the i-1th row to the ith row (could do columns with axis=1)
out_mat = mtx2 + np.roll(mtx2,shift = 1,axis=0)

#because Numpy adds the nth row to the first row, 
#it's undesired in structured data matrixes (ie timeseries) so 
#so I annul the first row in the output

out_mat = out_mat.astype(np.float) #np.nan are floats
out_mat[0,:] = np.nan
```